# Are the questions about Old Russian and Russian dialects on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are only questions about modern Russian on-topic? Or are the questions about Old Russian and Russian language dialects also welcomed on this site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Old Russian is still Russian, only old :)

Church Slavonic is not Russian (and has never been, it's old Bulgarian), but heavily influenced Russian and is heavily influenced by Russian, so I think for a lack of better place the questions about it should be asked here.

But which is most important, the same experts usually express interest to all three subjects.

Answer (score 13):

I feel that these questions should be on-topic. If they somehow prove to be problematic, it is never too late to make them off-topic.

Comment: I second this answer. As long as there is no other SE on old-Russian and church-Slavonic, they should be welcome here. Obviously, it's a field of different expertise and interest, however we should not ban such questions as long as we don't get too many unanswered ones.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @kotekzot. If the old-russian topics will grow out of control, they should be banned (a new section should be started at Area51). Otherwise they will not hurt anyone.

Comment: It is generally considered good form to post a comment instead of an answer to express agreement.

Comment: @kotekzot Sorry, my fault. I thought in terms of making your answer more complete, providing more arguments, not just agreeing with you. Anyway, I will be more accurate next time.

Comment: What would "out of control" mean? Lots of questions would mean popular. Maybe you mean lots of *bad* questions?

Comment: Hey, no problems. Comments are best used for providing clarification and context, while answers are more suited for posting something something significantly different (i.e. "They shouldn't be allowed, because ..." or "They should be allowed if they satisfy the following criteria ...". Up to you, of course.

Comment: @hippietrail If most of the questions in Russian language section will be devoted not to Russian but to Old-Russian and dialects, it won't be good.

Comment: @iHunter: Is it bad that most questions on Stack Exchange are devoted to `c#` and `java`? Some subfield or other is always going to be more popular than others. But I very much doubt that Old Russian or dialects would be the top two tags anyway (-:

Comment: @hippietrail I agree, there's nothing to discuss for now. If the problem will arise, we should be thinking about it, but not earlier.